# Timing out when trying to switch to iframe with Selenium for Python

Tags: python, selenium, iframe

When I have selenium click a button on the webpage, a popup opens and I've tried a few ways to switch to the iframe popup but I'm using

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until()
```

and after 10 seconds it will just timeout. I'm guessing it never recognizes the iframe and I'm sure it must be because I'm having it look for it incorrectly. Here is the HTML:

```html
<div class="indeed-apply-popup" tabindex="0" id="indeed-ia-1530049657884-0-modal" style="position: absolute; left: 216px; top: 80px;"><div class="indeed-apply-container" id="indeedapply-modal-preload-container" style="height: 572px; width: 540px;"><div class="indeed-apply-branding" id="indeedapply-modal-preload-branding"></div><div class="indeed-apply-bd" id="indeedapply-modal-preload-bd"><iframe name="indeedapply-modal-preload-iframe" id="indeedapply-modal-preload-iframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="https://apply.indeed.com/indeedapply/xpc?v=5#%7B%22cn%22:%22onESpqgxSb%22,%22ppu%22:%22https://www.indeed.com/robots.txt%22,%22lpu%22:%22https://apply.indeed.com/robots.txt%22,%22setupms%22:1530049660417,%22preload%22:true,%22iaUid%22:%221cgv11tjq1b2b0o4%22,%22parentURL%22:%22https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=it&amp;l=252C%2520FL&amp;vjk=ff1572a95b1b84bf%22%7D" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe></div></div></div>
```

the popup that contains the iframe has HTML like this:

```html
<div class="indeed-apply-popup" tabindex="0" id="indeed-ia-1530049657884-0-modal" style="position: absolute; left: 208px; top: 80px;"><div class="indeed-apply-container" id="indeedapply-modal-preload-container" style="height: 572px; width: 540px;"><div class="indeed-apply-branding" id="indeedapply-modal-preload-branding"></div><div class="indeed-apply-bd" id="indeedapply-modal-preload-bd">
```

The part of my code I'm using looks like this:

```
for item in page_results:
    item.click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'indeed-apply-button-label'))
    )
    apply_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('indeed-apply-button-label')
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, 'indeed-apply-button-label'))
    )
    apply_button.click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, 'indeedapply-modal-preload-iframe'))
    )
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='form-action-continue']"))
    )

    continue_button = driver.find_element_by_id('form-action-continue')
    continue_button.click()
```

But the error I get is:

```
line 70, in <module>
EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, "indeedapply-modal-preload-iframe"))
line 80, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

I've tried driver.switch_to.frame() on it's own after and before the WebDriverWait, still nothing. Even if I get it to not show the timeout message anymore, the following

```
continue_button
```

Is not recognizable and then I get an error saying the element doesn't exist.

Comment: Don't see any error on the line `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, 'indeedapply-modal-preload-iframe'))`, Can you cross check once again to be sure you want to switch to this frame only?

Comment: @DebanjanB I've been trying a few other alternatives since my post, and have ended up with `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='indeed-apply-bd']/iframe[0]"))
    )
    driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='indeed-apply-bd']/iframe[0]"))`

Which returns the same TimeoutException as before. So no progress yet, lol.

Comment: If you have to use `[0]` then there are multiple `iframes` identified through the locator strategy currently you are using and we have to work to construct a unique locator strategy. I would like to avoid an index in every possible way.

Comment: @DebanjanB Ah, ok. There aren't any other `iframes`, I was just trying as many possibilities as I could and figured I'd give that a shot. I've also tried 

`WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@id='indeed')]"))
    )`

And changed `contains` to `starts-with` but they don't seem to work.

Comment: @DebanjanB One thing I should mention is the `iframe` id and name are dynamic and will change based on the job that is clicked on the indeed search results page. So that's why I looked up to see if `contains` would work, but nope.

Comment: IMO, the `iframe` tag you mentioned within the question is not your intended `iframe` as it is a one liner element without any elements in it

Comment: Of-coarse, `iframes` with dynamic id and name must be treated as per their appearance

Comment: @DebanjanB there is another `iframe` tag within the original but it just says src and frameborder, not much else. The original `iframe` I posted has a elements within it like <html>, <body>,  and a few <div>'s

Comment: The `iframe` you published `<iframe name="indeedapply-modal-preload-iframe" id="indeedapply-modal-preload-iframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>` neither contains any element or any `src`. Possibly it's not your intended _iframe_. But there are chances it gets populated through _JavaScripts_ just before the moment you need to access it.

Comment: `<iframe name="indeedapply-modal-preload-iframe" id="indeedapply-modal-preload-iframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="https://apply.indeed.com/indeedapply/xpc?v=5#%7B%22cn%22:%22onESpqgxSb%22,%22ppu%22:%22https://www.indeed.com/robots.txt%22,%22lpu%22:%22https://apply.indeed.com/robots.txt% style="border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>`

When I mouse over the HTML in inspect on chrome, that is what is highlighted, but there are a couple of <div>'s it is inside of. if things are created through JS, what might I have to use to be able to switch frames?

Comment: You need to update the question with those `couple of <div>` to analyze what's going wrong

Comment: @DebanjanB updated thank you